# What am I looking for? <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I checked the other solutions on here but non are to do with my problem. So I dont think this is a duplicate. What is it that gives this error? I checked my scrollView and its not set to 0,0 and here is the code to my ImageView picker:

```
 imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate=self;
imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.allowsEditing=YES;


self.popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.button.bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

I cant see the problem, can someone tell me what I am looking for.

Comment: Print your button bounds - NSLog(@"Button bounds is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.button.bounds));

Comment: @InjectIOS the button bounds are `{{0, 0}, {100, 44}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set `delegate` of  `UIPopoverController`.

```
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
```

And not sure but Problem is `presentPopoverFromRect:self.button.bounds`

so give proper `CGRect` to it, might be solve your problem .
Such like

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20, 50, 70, 40);// set as you need 
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;    
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.scrollView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

> And also i don't know what is **inView:sender** , **sender** must be **UIView**.

Comment: seems to have worked, thank you. Could you elaborate on the problem I encountered?

Comment: i had not this types of issue generated ever, but i think it may be fixed, keep it up , good starting :)